# Casting as a form from a window handle

Tags: c#, winforms, casting

My C#.NET Windows application dynamically creates a bunch of forms with no name and no borders, this works fine, however I later need to find these forms and set them to be the top most forms. My current logic is to write the myForm.Handle to a string at the time of creation so I can refer to that handle later.

And this is where it fails, when I'm ready to set it to be the top most windows, I do this:

```
Form myForm = Form.FromHandle(sFormHandle);
if (myForm != null) { myForm.TopMost = true; }
```

The *sFormHandle* is a string and it expects a *IntPtr*, how can I convert it, or do this in some other way?

Many thanks.

Comment: Is it throwing an exception?  If so, what is the exception?  Something about not being able to cast?

Comment: Don't do this, the handle value will *change* when you set the TopMost property to true.  Instead of storing a string or IntPtr, store a reference to Form instead.

Comment: Didn't know the handles change and I am now adding the forms to a List and reference that later, it did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Handle property on a form is an IntPtr.
Why have you stored it as a string?

The solution here is to store the handle as an IntPtr, not a string.
Better than that, if this is all .net windows forms code, why not **keep a reference to the form** rather than the handle?

Edit: added emphasis. Consensus from community seems to be that references to the forms should be retained and the handles should not be relied upon.

Comment: Emphasis on "reference to the form"...handles can change.

Comment: yeah, i originally had quotes around 'solution' but thought that was too snarky. I completely agree with @DonBoitnott though, I can see no good reason to use handles over references to the forms here.

Comment: I believed handles were the safest way to look for a form. I am now adding the forms to a List "List<Form> formInstances = new List<Form>();" and reference that when needed. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Form fr = (Form)Form.FromHandle(new IntPtr(int.Parse("0")));

and beware of direct refrence to a class...
you better try WeakRefrence because of COM class models
if you use a direct refrence to a class,
the class will not unload till all the refrences are removed!